# unable to follow application of Weiner-Kolmogorov formula

Tags: z-transform

In a book I am reading, the author writes the following:

Let a series be denoted as $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} C_{j}\epsilon_{t-j}$, where the $C_{j}$ and $\epsilon_t$ are scalars.

Also, $C(z) =\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}C_{j} z^{j}$

Then, later on, quoting the author: "The z-transform of the sequence $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} C_{j+1} \epsilon_{t-j}$ is given by the Weiner-Kolmogorov formula" :

$\left[\frac{C(z)}{z}\right]_{+} = $

$z^{-1}(C(z) - C_{0})$

I had to skip a line in the above because there's something odd going on with the latex translator. Anyway, I've googled for z-transform and found many results. I've also googled for annihilator and Weiner-Kolmogorov formula and found many results. But none of the results have explained how above is derived. Could someone explain it or does anyone know of a good reference that explains it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are not telling me you need a latex translator to add formulas to your posts? BTW: Norbert W$\color{red}{ie}$ner is the name of the man.

Comment: No. Not telling you that. Some say Wiener. Some say Weiner. I'll go with the latter. He won't mind iether way.

Comment: Thanks but I used the correct name. Many results come up but nothing that led to me figuring out my question. It's an econometrics book that I'm reading and kind of specialized so maybe that's the problem. Book is "Linear Rational Expectations Models: A Users Guide" by Charles Whiteman but it's not on the net.

Comment: I observe that the expression $z^{-1}(C(z)-C_0)$ does not seem to involve any of the $\epsilon_k$ values, so it is unlikely to be correct. In general this looks like it is trying to use a convolution fact and a time-shift fact about $z$-transforms, but it forgets to include the transform of $\{\epsilon_t\}$. I also think that double-sided transforms $\{a_k\}_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \leftrightarrow \hat{A}(z)= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a_kz^{-k}$ are easier to work with.

Comment: Under a single-sided transform definition: If $\{c_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}\leftrightarrow C(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_kz^{k}$ then $\{c_{k+1}\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ transforms to $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_{k+1}z^{k}=\sum_{u=1}^{\infty}c_uz^{u-1}=z^{-1}\sum_{u=1}^{\infty} c_uz^u =z^{-1}(C(z)-c_0)$$ The pesky subtraction of $c_0$ arises because this is a single-sided transform rather than a double-sided transform. It is not clear if your book is using a "double-sided" z-transform definition but then taking the causal part, or if it is using a single-sided definition.

Comment: Michael: It will take me some time to absorb what you wrote but I'm sure it will be helpful. Whether I end up understanding it or not, I will email the author and ask him what you are concerned about. Your help is much appreciated and I'll try to respond with more info if I obtain it.

Comment: Which book exactly?

Comment: Hi: the book in the third comment but it's difficult if not impossible to get for free.

Comment: In other words, assuming the book says what you give above, then the  book has a simple typo/mistake (as most books do) and it is really giving you the transform of sequence $\{c_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$, not the transform of that sequence convolved with the $\{\epsilon_j\}$ sequence.

Comment: Hi Michael: Yes, you are correct. He left out the $\epsilon_j$ sequence but that's just a matter of writing $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} C_{j} \epsilon_{t-j} = C(L) \epsilon_t$ In a different section of the book, he replaces the $z$ with the lag operator $L$. It's all kind of confusing but, yes, he did leave out the $\epsilon_t$ which can be considered a typo. I think this book is actually some chapters or all of his thesis ( 40 years old. but age doesn't account for typos ).

Comment: As far as the one sidedness of the transform, that may have to do with that rational expectations econometrics almost always works in the time domain rather than the frequency domain. So, they tend to use $t=0$ rather than $t= -\infty$ as the beginning of the series.

Comment: I liked the way you solved it because it makes intuitive sense. One needs to rid of the first $C$ and then divide the whole thing by $z$ so that one doesn't get jumped. I still want to figure out how to get the same result using the Wiener-Kolmogorov formula. I found a book with a lot of examples so I think I'll be able to figure it out and will post here when that happens.

Comment: Since I only gave a book title that, for all intents and purposes, does not exist in school libraries, here's something that somewhat explains what all this stuff is about in case someone is interested. It's still very "obtuse" ( atleast for my brain ) but you can atleast get an idea of what it's all about. The hopefully good examples that I recently found are in a textbook which I'll also include in a link below.

Comment: https://www.minneapolisfed.org/research/staff-reports/a-note-on-wienerkolmogorov-prediction-formulas-for-rational-expectations-models

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Macroeconomic-Economic-econometrics-mathematical-economics/dp/0126197504/ref=sr_1_8?crid=3G59K7PRQSFAQ&keywords=sargent+macroeconomic+theory&qid=1691218114&sprefix=sargent+macroeconomic+theory%2Caps%2C194&sr=8-8